# UML - Should Activity Diagram show all possibilities of an activity or just the actions required to complete?

Tags: uml

We've been asked to create an activity diagram to illustrate the occurrence of one non-trivial action of an app we're creating.

Should an activity diagram show all possibilites of an activity, or just those actions undertaken in the specific activity?

For example, let's say the activiy diagram is about processing an order for an item through your app...should the diagram have an decision action or an interrupting edge that says "Order cancelled?" (Yes/No) or should it simply show what happens when a successful order is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Should Activity Diagram show just the actions required to complete?* Simply yes. You do not create a single AD for a model but as many as needed. So a single AD focuses on a certain (part-) scenario.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But yes to which part of the question lol? Yes to all possibilities or yes to just the actions required to complete? I'm guessing it's the second part, but just wanted to be clear!

Comment: Qwerty_so, you're a legend mate. Thank you.

Comment: More like Lucky Luke (if you happen to know him). Shooting faster than his shadow. Unfortunately in the wrong direction xD